# animated gif speed, nice in ImageMagick or GraphicsMagic, slow in powerpoint

Tags: windows, imagemagick, animation, animated-gif, graphicsmagick

I have *N* tiff files.  In linux I can do `convert -delay 0 -loop 0 *.tiff output.gif`

In linux, using `gm animate *.tif` I get a nice smooth rotation at a nice speed.  And if I recreate *N* tiff files to have *2N* files the rotation slows but is still good, what one would expect.  Basically 180, 360, 720, or 1440 total files making up one revolution.

In powerpoint the animation is **horrible**.

Is there a way to use `convert` to make the animated gif display acceptably in windows [powerpoint] ?

Is there a better way to display a simple 800x600 or 1920x1080 animation in Windows?

Comment: Is it Powerpoint *per se*, or the extra load of that app plus the video output overloading a PC? Try that PPT on another, faster PC with video card.

Comment: Not sure what qualifies as "horrible" but perhaps try `-delay 1`? Alternately, you could just export the animation as video and loop it in PowerPoint itself.

Comment: pc has quadro P1000 card, win10, nothing else running; displayed in internet explorer the animated gif does half a rotation then gets slower to where it does 0.5° rotation every 2 seconds; powerpoint not as bad but choppy and slow